# Ruby Anagrams Checker

Tags: ruby

I am quite new to Ruby, coming from a JavaScript background. I wrote this simple Ruby script that finds whether two strings are anagrams or not.

To run it: ruby ruby_anagrams.rb 'script1' 'script2'

I am looking for comments and a code review on my script. Can I do anything better? Is this good Rubyism?

```
# removing whitespace (in case of multi-word anagrams), converting to lowercase and getting
# array representations:
string_1_arr = ARGV[0].gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase.split("")
string_2_arr = ARGV[1].gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase.split("")

if string_1_arr.size != string_2_arr.size
  puts "Not anagrams"
  exit
end

string_1_arr.each do |c|
  print c, " ",string_2_arr, "\n" # debug statement, but left here 'cuz the output looks cool

  # just delete would delete all occurences of the same letter, e.g. "food" would become
  # "fd" if we delete 'o', which is obviously wrong. Have to use delete_at(index) instead
  if i = string_2_arr.index(c)
    string_2_arr.delete_at i 
  else
    puts "Not anagrams"
    exit
  end
end

puts "Anagrams!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should abstract the code to avoid duplication. Also, use a counter with O(n) performance:

```
module Enumerable # or require 'facets/enumerable/frequency'
  def frequency
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |item, counter| counter[item] += 1 }  
  end
end

def anagrams?(s1, s2)
  frequency = proc { |s| s.gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase.chars.frequency }
  frequency.(s1) == frequency.(s2)
end

if ARGV.size != 2
  $stderr.puts("Need two words")
  exit(1)
elsif anagrams?(*ARGV)
  puts("Anagrams")
else
  puts("Not anagrams")
end
```

Comment: +1 nice! Not knowing facet's `frequency`, I was thinking something along the lines of `group_by` and then mapping values by `count` - same result, but a roundabout way of getting there compared to yours, so I didn't pursue it, and just used Jerry Coffin's suggestion. Btw, wouldn't `reduce` be more appropriate than `each_with_object`?

Comment: It would be a bit uglier: `reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |counter, item| counter[item] += 1; counter }`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, of course. Hadn't thought it through

Comment: The tradeoff made here is for increased memory usage (for the hash) to work in `O(n)` time. If you had limited memory you could do `s1.downcase.gsub(/\s/,'').chars.sort` and compare the two arrays, for in-place memory but `O(n log n)` complexity.

Answer (score 2):

[Jerry Coffin's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60167/14370) is spot on regarding how one might solve this task more efficiently. I'll just look at your code, as-is

- I see duplication. You have to do the same thing to both strings, so make it method:

  ```
  def characters_in_string(string)
    string.downcase.gsub(/\s/, '').split
  end
  ```
- There's also some duplication in that there are 2 exit points for your script. Again, it could be cleaner to wrap the "meat" of your script in a method that simply returns a boolean (for instance, `anagrams?(string1, string2)`).
- You might want to check `ARGC` before doing anything. If only 1 string is passed to the script, you can skip everything else.
- Just to follow linux/unix scripting conventions, you could consider exiting with a non-zero status, if the anagram check fails. I know it's not really required for this but it's good practice nonetheless.

---

Using Jerry Coffin's approach, you get something like

```
def characters_in_string(string)
  string.downcase.gsub(/\s/, '').chars.sort
end

def anagrams?(string1, string2)
  characters_in_string(string1) == characters_in_string(string2)
end

if anagrams?(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
  puts "Anagrams!"
else
  puts "Not anagrams"
  exit 1
end
```

I've left out the argument checking as an exercise to the reader